# How to read /dev/random in python

Tags: python, unix

I read in a book that `/dev/random` is like an infinite file, but when I set up the following codes to see what the content look like, it prints nothing.

```
with open("/dev/random") as f:
    for i in xrange(10):
        print f.readline()
```

BTW, when I tried this with `/dev/urandom`, it worked.

Comment: Why are you reading *lines* from a random binary device?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So it's binary content inside? Then `readline` must be waiting for a non-exist carriage return. But why does it works for /dev/urandom then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is outputting random bytes, not random lines.  You see nothing until you get a newline, which will only happen every 256 bytes on average.  The reason `/dev/urandom` appears to work is simply that it operates faster.  Wait longer, read less, or use `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: golja, no?  `/dev/urandom` is a separate device, which only generates pseudo-random data, unlike `/dev/random` which attempts to do a proper job (but requires a lot more time to do so).

Comment: all random data on Linux is pseudo random

Comment: @MichaelMartinez The comment I'm responding to seems to be gone; but yes, the difference is how much effort is being put into making it less obviously pseudorandom.

Answer (score 20):

FWIW, the preferred way of accessing this stream (or something like it) in a semi-portable way is *[os.urandom()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.urandom)*

Comment: `os.urandom` returns `/dev/urandom`, a different stream (less secure, yet faster) on Linux systems.

Answer (score 8):

```
with open("/dev/random", 'rb') as f:
    print repr(f.read(10))
```